# Why do I get different hash encoding results in SQL Server depending on how I convert a string?

Tags: sql-server

Assume that I have a database table with the following columns:

**ProteinSequence**

```
id (Integer)
AASequence (nvarchar(max))
```

Also assume that this table only has one entry

where AASequence = 'PLEINEQMMDLHSSLRTWCYFCYNAALHVPGNLTTQLMAKAMEPNAINIHCSEPTDYQQQGRSAASEWGLGIWQIVNLCHMCLGLYACVKTGSFNGCDGGGFQGIWCCWGSFTDYSLDDALGEKWCKEMRPYAHQINDVLIDMPLEFQHDSSIQWPQKACDNNQSTMTFWLAEKIFTFFQGLKQMDSTFQDNCPHATQNQKAMQVRAGSRATEAYCINTSDFMCLSKKWMAACKTKIVDGFQFSQFCWSNMDWATVYICANLTNWFYTGATSSKLVDQVWRESIVGQMFTHLYCPNVCIVPEYCEEMCFNRSQAQCMSADMCSLRSKQCTTELFCYICAGFLGGNVAWNGQRWWETDMYIEYWLIWTLQWHCNKHMHGCSTESRMHEYDDQQILELKNIHVWPFPGYEEYYTECRPEEMTVMQHTASMGSEAHNDLKNAWILDGSDMIADIWEVNICESQPQWWVNEWGKYLCSHKHDGLIDE'

When I perform the following query on it:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    AASequence, 
    LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', AASequence), 2)) AS noconvertvarcharmd5,
    LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR, UPPER(AASequence))), 2)) AS uppermd5, 
FROM 
    [EOI].[dbo].[ProteinSequence]
WHERE
    AASequence = 'PLEINEQMMDLHSSLRTWCYFCYNAALHVPGNLTTQLMAKAMEPNAINIHCSEPTDYQQQGRSAASEWGLGIWQIVNLCHMCLGLYACVKTGSFNGCDGGGFQGIWCCWGSFTDYSLDDALGEKWCKEMRPYAHQINDVLIDMPLEFQHDSSIQWPQKACDNNQSTMTFWLAEKIFTFFQGLKQMDSTFQDNCPHATQNQKAMQVRAGSRATEAYCINTSDFMCLSKKWMAACKTKIVDGFQFSQFCWSNMDWATVYICANLTNWFYTGATSSKLVDQVWRESIVGQMFTHLYCPNVCIVPEYCEEMCFNRSQAQCMSADMCSLRSKQCTTELFCYICAGFLGGNVAWNGQRWWETDMYIEYWLIWTLQWHCNKHMHGCSTESRMHEYDDQQILELKNIHVWPFPGYEEYYTECRPEEMTVMQHTASMGSEAHNDLKNAWILDGSDMIADIWEVNICESQPQWWVNEWGKYLCSHKHDGLIDE';
```

I get different hash encodings in SQL Server 2017 depending on whether I convert the input sequence or not. Here are the results

No conversion: 76efbe0427aa717507930168758c664d

With conversion: 85b592208da2d9a2415420009fe56ceb

I also discovered that this discrepancy is also not happening on very short strings like "ATCG"

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Context: This behavior was identified during code reviews looking for causes of why we had duplicate entries in the database. Note: We were using MD5 checksums to determine the uniqueness of a string of letters.

Comment: Is the first one also varchar? Possibly nvarchar, which would be a different binary representation?

Comment: Yeah, `nvarchar` is two bytes per character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CONVERT(varchar,upper(AASequence))` truncates to 30 characters, you need to explicitly provide the type length, eg `CONVERT(varchar(500),upper(AASequence))`

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b4c4b/5

Answer (score -2):

The following function calls produce different plaintexts.

```
AASequence

CONVERT(varchar,upper(AASequence)))
```

Different plaintexts in = different hashes out.

Let AASequence = The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Then, upper(AASequence) = THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG.

Comment: The OPs string was all upper case.